# Best way to create a new repository after executing git-filter-repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-remote, git-filter-repo

I want to split my repository and my conclusion is that I should create a new repository where I remove the unwanted parts using `git-filter-repo`.

After reading a lot of documentation around it, I'm pretty sure how I should use `git-filter-repo`, but I'm missing how I should execute the other steps in a correct way.

This is the method that I came up with, but I would like your advice on if it is the correct way, or if there is something I'm missing.
I'm using bitbucket for my repository, and when I tried it out the bitbucket web interface is very slow and sometimes it fails to list branches etc.

First I create a new empty repo on bitbucket, repo2.
Then I execute the following sequence:

```
git clone --bare --mirror https://user@bitbucket.com/workspace/repo1
cd repo1
git filter-repo --path <path to remove> --invert-paths
git remote add origin https://user@bitbucket.com/workspace/repo2
git push --mirror
```

Note that `git filter-repo` will remove the original remote path to origin.

I'm not sure if I should use --mirror or something else on clone and push. some documents say that I should use `git push -u origin --all`, but I guess that some references would be missing after that.

Why is bitbucket so slow in listing my new repo2? It is also listing the size to only be a few kB, but it seem to contain everything I want. Is it just that it takes some time for the servers to update?

Comment: `--all` for `git push` means *all branch names*, i.e., `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`. `--mirror` means *all refs*, so it includes tag names as well. I'd guess that Bitbucket is indeed just being slow to update some statistics.

Answer (score 1):

I got some support directly from bitbucket staff, that confirmed that this method is correct. However, the laggy response in the web gui did not solve itself over time.
The solution seem to be to ask bitbucket support to run `git gc -- aggressive` on the server to "repair" the repository by removing dangling pointers etc.

I also tried to run `git gc -- aggressive` locally before pushing the repo, this improved the situation a lot, but not as good as running it on the server.

Since I could not find this issue in any other posts, I hope that someone else have use for this information.

Comment: I have a follow up question, other developers that are working on the same repository, should use a fresh clone of the repository once the changes are pushed? Since we do `git push -u origin --all`, we push everything to remote. I tried with a dummy repo, but a dev's local git was showing a bunch of conflicts. its safer to just make a new clone?

Comment: Yes you should always use a fresh clone after this type of operation since the history will be rewritten. It might also be good to keep the old repo as a backup for a while.